# How to search a row

Tags: excel, row, vba

I want my macro to be able to search a specific row for the text in question, so that it just searches that row and no other. For example, when you type in "dave", it should only search in row E for "dave".

```
Dim Answer, Reply
Dim b As Range

Answer = Application.InputBox("Enter the text to search for.", "Search Tool")

With Rows

  Set c = .Find(Answer, LookIn:=xlValues)

    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = c.Address
          Do
          Reply = MsgBox("Has this piece been edited? " & c.Address & _
          " which has a value of " & c.Value & "?", vbQuestion + _
          vbYesNoCancel, "Cell Hi-Liter")

            If Reply = vbYes Then
             c.Select
             Selection.Copy
             Selection.Offset(0, 1).Select
             ActiveSheet.Paste
             Exit Do
            End If

             Set c = .FindNext(c)
             Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress

                Else
                   MsgBox "Your search text was not found.", vbOKOnly, "Text Not Found"
      End If

End With


End Sub
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: and where is your problem?

Comment: I just can't seem to create the function to search in a specific row. It just chucks out errors.

Comment: Row 'E' doesn't exist - do you mean you want to search column E in each row for 'Dave'?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to find "Dave" in column E, the use the following code. This code is just for reference. If it finds Dave in Column E, it enters the confirmation on the column F.

```
Sub FindDave()
    Dim rngToFind As Range

    Set rngToFind = ActiveSheet.Columns("E:E")

    Dim c As Range
    Dim firstAddress As String

    With rngToFind
        Set c = .Find("Dave", LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = c.Address
            Do
                c.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Found on my left"
                Set c = .FindNext(c)
            Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

If you are not looking to find "Dave" in a particular column, then please do let us know where exactly you are trying to find.

Hope this helps.
Vikas B